# Master/Detail - setColumnState(...) updates state, but the table does not change

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm using the following ag-grid libraries:

- "@ag-grid-community/all-modules": "^22.1.1",
- "@ag-grid-community/angular": "^22.0.0",
- "@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules": "22.1.1",

I have a Master/Detail grid, and I have each of the detail containers expanded. I'm trying to programmatically change the states of each detail table, but it doesn't appear to be working.

Below is the piece of code I am using to set the state of each detail table:

```
    this.gridApi.forEachDetailGridInfo((params) => {
      console.log(`Before: ${JSON.stringify(params.columnApi.getColumnState())}`);
      params.columnApi.setColumnState(<state json>);
      console.log(`After: ${JSON.stringify(params.columnApi.getColumnState())}`);
    });
```

As you can see, I am logging the result.

```
Before: [{"colId": "column1", "hide": false, "aggFunc": null, "width": 110, "pivotIndex": null, "pinned": null, "rowGroupIndex": null}, {"colId": "column2", "hide": false, "aggFunc": null, "width": 200, "pivotIndex": null, "pinned": null, "rowGroupIndex": null}, {"colId": "column3", "hide": false, "aggFunc": null, "width": 200, "pivotIndex": null, "pinned": null, "rowGroupIndex": null}, {"colId": "column4", "hide": false, "aggFunc": null, "width": 200, "pivotIndex": null, "pinned": null, "rowGroupIndex": null}, {"colId": "column5", "hide": false, "aggFunc": null, "width": 200, "pivotIndex": null, "pinned": null, "rowGroupIndex": null}, {"colId": "column6", "hide": false, "aggFunc": null, "width": 200, "pivotIndex": null, "pinned": null, "rowGroupIndex": null}, {"colId": "column7", "hide": false, "aggFunc": null, "width": 200, "pivotIndex": null, "pinned": null, "rowGroupIndex": null}, {"colId": "column8", "hide": false, "aggFunc": null, "width": 200, "pivotIndex": null, "pinned": null, "rowGroupIndex": null}, {"colId": "column9", "hide": false, "aggFunc": null, "width": 200, "pivotIndex": null, "pinned": null, "rowGroupIndex": null}, {"colId": "column10", "hide": false, "aggFunc": null, "width": 200, "pivotIndex": null, "pinned": null, "rowGroupIndex": null}, {"colId": "column11", "hide": false, "aggFunc": null, "width": 200, "pivotIndex": null, "pinned": null, "rowGroupIndex": null}, {"colId": "column12", "hide": false, "aggFunc": null, "width": 200, "pivotIndex": null, "pinned": null, "rowGroupIndex": null}]

After: [{"colId": "column1", "hide": false, "aggFunc": null, "width":200, "pivotIndex": null, "pinned": null, "rowGroupIndex": null}, {"colId": "column2", "hide": false, "aggFunc": null, "width":110, "pivotIndex": null, "pinned": null, "rowGroupIndex": null}, {"colId": "column7", "hide": false, "aggFunc": null, "width":200, "pivotIndex": null, "pinned": null, "rowGroupIndex": null}, {"colId": "column3", "hide": false, "aggFunc": null, "width":200, "pivotIndex": null, "pinned": null, "rowGroupIndex": null}, {"colId": "column8", "hide": false, "aggFunc": null, "width":200, "pivotIndex": null, "pinned": null, "rowGroupIndex": null}, {"colId": "column4", "hide": false, "aggFunc": null, "width":200, "pivotIndex": null, "pinned": null, "rowGroupIndex": null}, {"colId": "column5", "hide": false, "aggFunc": null, "width":200, "pivotIndex": null, "pinned": null, "rowGroupIndex": null}, {"colId": "column6", "hide": false, "aggFunc": null, "width":200, "pivotIndex": null, "pinned": null, "rowGroupIndex": null}, {"colId": "column9", "hide": false, "aggFunc": null, "width":200, "pivotIndex": null, "pinned": null, "rowGroupIndex": null}, {"colId": "column10", "hide": true, "aggFunc": null, "width":200, "pivotIndex": null, "pinned": null, "rowGroupIndex": null}, {"colId": "column11", "hide": true, "aggFunc": null, "width":200, "pivotIndex": null, "pinned": null, "rowGroupIndex": null}, {"colId": "column12", "hide": true, "aggFunc": null, "width":200, "pivotIndex": null, "pinned": null, "rowGroupIndex": null}]
```

I clearly see from the log that the state changes, however the columns appear exactly the same before and after.

Am I missing a step?

**Edit:** I should also mention that my master table has a few pinned columns. I've found that when you have pinned columns, two duplicate detail tables are created. But I've already eliminated the possibility that this state is being applied to one and not the other